# Is there a way to show the current TFS workspace in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, tfs

I'm looking for a way to have the current TFS workspace displayed in Visual Studio.

It's visible when I open the Source Control Explorer (or Pending Changes), but I want it to be visible too when I'm editing code. So for example showing it in the toolbar, or in the window titlebar, or in the bottom status bar, doesn't matter as long as I can see it with a single glance.

Any tips?

Comment: Well, part of the problem is that Visual Studio doesn't necessarily **have** a current TFS workspace.  You can have a Solution that's bound to a particular TFS workspace, you can have Source Control Explorer open to a *different* TFS workspace, and you can have the Pending Changes View open as *still a different* TFS workspace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a add on that shows this info, you can dock it somewhere :

http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/384a4952-6b6f-4391-bc59-1b2bd38e1baf

Comment: Yes... that's what I already said in my question :-(. I'm looking for a way to *always* see it, without having to click open the Source Control Explorer (or Pending Changes).

Comment: oh sorry, somehow i overlooked this, but what you really need is second (or third) monitor so you can have all this windows open ;)

Comment: That's perfect, thanks man!
*Edit: how did you find this? I searched all over, but couldn't find anything...

Comment: by accident :) I was looking for similar TFS addon on Visual Studio gallery

Answer (score 4):

You can use the "Rename Visual Studio Window Title" extension https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/f3f23845-5b1e-4811-882f-60b7181fa6d6 and use the [workspaceName] attribute. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of options to do this without an additional plugin.

- Use the Properties view

  1. Select the solution, a project, or any file in Solution Explorer
  2. Press F4 to go to the Properties view.  The full path to your solution will be shown.
  3. Note that right-clicking the solution or project and selecting Properties (Alt-Enter) will take you to the Properties Pages which doesn't have the information you want.
- Use the Source Control Explorer

  1. Opening Source Control Explorer will show you the last accessed workspace.  Most of the time, this will be the workspace for the solution you are working on.  However, if you have had two Visual Studio sessions open for different workspaces, I have seen the first VS session switch to the workspace of the other VS session.
- Use the Pending Changes view

  1. Pending Changes will show the workspace just under the header for the view.
  2. You can get to Pending Changes through:

     - Team Explorer => Pending Changes
     - View => Other Windows => Pending Changes
- Hover the mouse over an open file, the tooltip will show the full path to the file.